# Error while running Zeppelin paragraphs in Spark on Linux cluster in Azure HdInsight

Tags: linux, azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight, apache-zeppelin

I have been following this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-apache-spark-use-zeppelin-notebook/) in order to set up Zeppelin on a Spark cluster (version 1.5.2) in HDInsight, on Linux. Everything worked fine, I have managed to successfully connect to the Zeppelin notebook through the SSH tunnel. However, when I try to run any kind of paragraph, the first time I get the following error:

> java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: wasb

After getting this error, if I try to rerun the paragraph, I get another error:

> java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
>   at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)

These errors occur regardless of the code I enter, even if there is no reference to the hdfs. What I'm saying is that I get the "No FileSystem" error even for a trivial scala expression, such as parallelize.

Is there a missing configuration step?

Comment: It looks like they updated the script. I just tried the updated version and it worked for my Spark 1.5.2 cluster.

Comment: You are correct, they have updated the script and indeed it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am download the tar ball that the script that you pointed to as I type. But want I am guessing is that your zeppelin install and spark install are not complete to work with wasb. In order to get spark to work with wasb you need to add some jars to the Class path. To do this you need to add something like this to your spark-defaults.conf (the paths might be different in HDInsights, this is from HDP on IaaS)

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/hadoop/lib/azure-storage-2.2.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/hadoop/lib/microsoft-windowsazure-storage-sdk-0.6.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/hadoop/hadoop-azure-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath /usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/hadoop/lib/azure-storage-2.2.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/hadoop/lib/microsoft-windowsazure-storage-sdk-0.6.0.jar:/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/hadoop/hadoop-azure-2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557.jar
```

Once you have spark working with wasb, or next step is make those sames jar in zeppelin class path. A good way to test your setup is make a notebook that prints your env vars and class path.

```
sys.env.foreach(println(_))

val cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader
cl.asInstanceOf[java.net.URLClassLoader].getURLs.foreach(println)
```

Also looking at the install script, it trying to pull the zeppelin jar from wasb, you might want to change that config to somewhere else while you try some of these changes out. (zeppelin.sh)

```
export SPARK_YARN_JAR=wasb:///apps/zeppelin/zeppelin-spark-0.5.5-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I hope this helps, if you are still have problems I have some other ideas, but would start with these first.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried your steps but, unfortunately, I wasn't able to get it running. I still got the same errors. However, it seemed that the issue was because of the script pointed out in the tutorial, which was for a different version of spark (1.5.1). They have updated the script and now everything is working as it should be.